# iPhone Not Deleting the Settings

Tags: iphone, sdk, settings

I have just installed the latest update to the iPhone.

I also have deleted my app from the iPhone and noticed that a previous install of my app has left the Settings bundle on my phone after I dis-installed the app.  Now, I have a Settings bundle without the related app.

This should not be possible as the older version sandbox should have been cleaned up or deleted when I dis-installed the previous (older version ) of my app.

What's going on?  How did this happen?  What programmatically happen that could even allow the Settings bundle to persist?

Comment: Certainly shouldn't happen. Was that with a released or a beta iOS? Maybe you have found a bug and should report it.

Comment: You meant un-installed right...?

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this situation, I did a full restore to the original factory settings and this eliminates the app Settings bundle that had no related app.  Restoring your contacts, etc did not cause an issue.

Having said this, it still seems strange that you can un-install an app and have the settings bundle remain.  But, it is a good design for their to be different sandboxes for different installs of the same app which keeps everything ring fenced.

Comment: Adam: Yes, it was a released version of the iOS software.  I always stay away from beta versions as I am a newbie and have no idea of what a software version is doing or if it is my stupid programming.

I would report it if I could reproduce it but it has not happened again.  [ I am wondering if there is always some random number error generator in the build function just to throw us newbie pledges a Maalox moment. ]

Lukya...Yes, I meant un-installed.